# How to run a specific shell script when a new user added

Tags: bash, ubuntu-18.04

How do I run a specific shell script (say `someScript.sh`) when a new user added? I tried adding the `chmod +x` to `someScript.sh` and added following command to `/usr/local/sbin/adduser.local`.

```
User=$1    
someScript.sh $User
```

I get error that `adduser.local: someScript.sh: not found`. However the command works fine in terminal.

Comment: Did you try providing the complete path to someScript.sh?

Comment: @SiKing It worked with the complete path. It could cause some issue if I place the files in some other folder in future, but that's the issue for other day. There were couple of more issues like `"$'\r': command not found"`, so I had to ensure that file `adduser.local` is UNIX compatible with help of utility `dos2unix`. Finally made it work, Thanks again for help.